# Shimmer for android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I would like to use shimmer for android: [Link to github](https://github.com/RomainPiel/Shimmer-android)
But it requires minSdk 14 and my project is using minSdk 10.
I would like to keep minSdk 10 and still be able to use shimmer.
Is there any fork or workaround for this project helping me doing this? Thank you.

Comment: Have you googled? Have you pulled the project from github, changed the minsdk version, and seen how dependant Shimmer is on sdk version 14? Maybe you can transcode it yourself

Comment: It worked, thank you. I created a fork for it. I also had to change some configuration in build.gradle. The fork is available here: https://github.com/heetch/Shimmer-android